# Compiler fail with qsort

Tags: ibm-midrange, qsort, rpgle, rpg

I use Create Bound RPG Program (CRTBNDRPG) with a sample program

Job log

```
Ownership of object QSORTR in QTEMP type *MODULE changed.       
Definition not found for symbol 'QSORT'.                        
Program QSORTR in library QTEMP not created.                    
Compilation failed. Program QSORTR not created in library QTEMP.
```

The code is

```
     H DFTACTGRP(*NO) BNDDIR('QC2LE')

     D qsort           PR                  ExtProc('qsort')
     D   base                          *   value
     D   num                         10U 0 value
     D   width                       10U 0 value
     D   compare                       *   procptr value

      ** Sort the array by DtlItem
     c                   callp     qsort(%addr(Order1): numitems:
     c                                %size(Order): %paddr('SORTBYITEM'))
     c                   For       idx= 1 to numitems
     c                   eval      tmpstr = order1(idx).DtlItem
     c                   Dsply                   tmpstr
     c                   Endfor
...
```

i copy from here [2003-12-09 如何於 RPG中 針對所定義的資料結構(DataStructure)排序？](https://blog.xuite.net/vengoal/as400/4959115)

Comment: You should show the code where you are calling `qsort`.  All you've shown is the prototype.

Comment: i copy from here [2003-12-09 如何於 RPG中 針對所定義的資料結構(DataStructure)排序？](https://blog.xuite.net/vengoal/as400/4959115)
sorry, because it show 「It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details」, i can't show all the code.

Comment: i found out, can't not use `ExtProc('QSORT')`, should be `ExtProc('qsort')`

Comment: Yes, C/C++ has mixed case procedures names by default.  RPGIV also supports mixed case.  So you need to be careful with what you use in `extproc()`.  Which we probably would have caught if you'd posted your code directly.  The example you posted did have `extproc('qsort')`

Comment: When you posting code that is failing in some way, you should post it as it is when it fails, not the corrected version. This way the question and solution make sense. As it is, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

it should work.  [jon paris article on qsort](https://www.itjungle.com/2012/01/25/fhg012512-story02/)

here is the article in code:

```
** test0260r: sort data struct array using qsort.
h option(*srcstmt:*nodebugio)
h bnddir('QC2LE')

** --------------------------- test0260r ---------------------------
** test0260r: sort data struct array using qsort.
dtest0260r        pr                  extpgm('TEST0260R')

** --------------------------- qsort --------------------------------
d qsort           pr                  extproc('qsort')
d  dataStart                      *   value
d  elemCount                    10u 0 value
d  elemSize                     10u 0 value
d  compareFunc                    *   ProcPtr value

** --------------------------- test0260r ---------------------------
** test0260r: sort data struct array using qsort.
dtest0260r        pi

d pSeqProcedure   s               *   ProcPtr
d                                     Inz(%PAddr(SeqNameCityState))

** -------------------- customerData -----------------------
d customerData    ds                  Dim(1000) Qualified
d  name                         30a
d  address1                     40a
d  address2                     40a
d  city                         30a
d  state                         2a
d  zip                           5s 0

d customerCount   s             10i 0
 /free
      customerCount  = 50 ;

   qsort ( %Addr(customerData)
         : customerCount
         : %Size(customerData)
         : pSeqProcedure );

      *inlr       = '1' ;
      return ;
 /end-free


** ------------------- seqNameCityState -------------------------
p SeqNameCityState...
p                 b
d                 pi            10i 0
d elementA                            LikeDS(customerData)
d elementB                            LikeDS(customerData)

d high            s             10i 0 inz(1)
d low             s             10i 0 inz(-1)
d equal           s             10i 0 inz(0)
 /Free

   If elementA.state > elementB.state;
     Return HIGH;
   ElseIf elementA.state < elementB.state;
     Return LOW;
   ElseIf elementA.city > elementB.city;
     Return HIGH;
   ElseIf elementA.city < elementB.city;
     Return LOW;
   ElseIf elementA.name > elementB.name;
     Return HIGH;
   ElseIf elementA.name < elementB.name;
     Return LOW;
   Else;
     Return EQUAL;
   EndIf;

 /end-free
p                 e
```

to compile:

```
CRTRPGMOD MODULE(TEST0260R) SRCFILE(QRPGLESRC) DBGVIEW(*ALL)   
CRTPGM PGM(TEST0260R)
```

or

```
CRTBNDRPG PGM(TEST0260R) SRCFILE(QRPGLESRC) DFTACTGRP(*NO) DBGVIEW(*ALL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your anowser, i finally found my problem, it because i use uppercase `EXTPROC('QSORT')`, should be `EXTPROC('qsort')`